# show localized Year and Month

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I want to show Year and Month by localized format. 
for example by locale.

2016年11月 or Nov 2016

I found NSDateFormatterLongStyle but, it shows Year , Month and day.

How to get it?

```
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];  
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];  
NSString *dateStringLongStyle = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
NSLog(@"LongStyle   : %@", dateStringLongStyle);
```

LongStyle   : 2009年7月16日 23:54:37JST

LongStyle   : July 16, 2009 11:56:47 PM GMT+09:00

Answer (score 0):

I found dateFormatFromTemplate, and solved my problem

```
  NSDateFormatter monthAndYearFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  NSString *dateComponents = @"YMMM";
  NSString *dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:dateComponents options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
  [monthAndYearFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
```

Comment: This isn't quite right. You want to use `@"yMMM"`, not `@"YMMM"`.